# What workbooks (guidelines) can be helpful for solving math logical exercies?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

I am wondering which workbooks can be helpful in solving the following task:
For an individual range I = {a,b} show that:

$$
\begin{array}{l}{\text { (a) }\{p(a), \forall X(p(X) \rightarrow q(X))\}=q(a)} \\ {\text { (b) }\{\forall X(p(X) \rightarrow q(X)), \forall X \neg q(X)\}=\forall X \neg p(X)} \\ {\text { (c) }\{p(a), \forall X(p(X) \rightarrow q(X))\} |=\exists X q(X)}\end{array}
$$

As I understood, this task is connected to Horn clause, math logic and predicates. But deeping into these topics didn't make me closer to ideas for solving exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this answer is not really correct, because file (answer) is in Russian. But finally I found some approaches for solving above mentioned task in this presentation:

http://cloud.bogdan.co/s/D2NCxtZdxbYtBeo

To be sure that this file wouldn't be occasionally deleted, I duplicate it in another cloud:

https://1drv.ms/p/s!As7Xx8xokIvflqhWHZFeQd-8ljzZrg?e=LX7JFL